# Default value using AMPScript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I want to show a default value "Friend" if firstname is Empty or unknown And it should show the name if it is there. But this is not working. Can anyone help me this.

```
%%[var @Firstname, @Email 
set @Email = EmailAddress
set @Firstname = lookup("Salutation_DE","Firstname","EmailAddress", @Email)]%%  

%%[IF Empty(@Firstname) OR @Firstname == "Unknown" THEN]%%
set @Firstname = "Friend" 
%%[ENDIF]%%
```

Dear `%%=v(@Firstname)=%%`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this?

```
%%[
IF Empty(@Firstname) OR @Firstname == "Unknown" THEN
 set @Firstname = "Friend"
ENDIF
]%%
```

Dear `%%=v(@Firstname)=%%`

Comment: That should be it.  @r suri you closed your ampscript bracket too early.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the response!!
That was a silly mistake of data error.

Below is the code:

```
%%[ IF Empty(@Firstname) OR @Firstname == "Unknown" THEN 
set @defaultValue = "Friend" 
Else
set @defaultValue = @Firstname
Endif]%%

Dear %%=v(@defaultValue)=%%,
```